# Objective C - can a custom built tab bar be hidden in some views in a multiview application?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, multiview

I am new to programing and am trying to create a multiview application. To start, I can successfully create a multiview application without the prebuilt tab bar.  What I'd like to do now is hide the view selecton list in certain views. As it stands now with my application, the view selector is constant on all views, which eats up some valuable real-estate. With some views I'd like it to be visible and others hidden.

So far my references and my other research have come up short. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `UIViewController`'s `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES`. The tab bar is then hidden when the user navigates a level deeper in one of your tab's navigation controllers.

Comment: Thank you Johan for the help. I will play around with it.